# Open-source Java library to mimic Excel's "Text Import Wizard"?

Tags: java, excel, open-source, text, csv

Microsoft Excel has a nice "Text Import Wizard" to help load files that are not .xls or .csv files.  The user specifies the delimiter used (or the fixed width), as well as some information about column types (general, dates, etc.).  Are there any open-source Java libraries that can mimic a similar sort of functionality and allow one to put the results into home-brewed data structures?

To clarify, suppose I have a data structure to represent essentially a 2D spreadsheet.  I would like to populate that data structure from a file that might be tab-delimited, comma-delimited, etc (these files might be huge BTW).  I know there exist a bunch of CSV readers, but are there any that also support the type of extra markup related to column types and other types of customized pre-processing?

I'm not an open-source expert, but I would it to be under a license that wouldn't force me to release my source code.  Thanks.

Comment: this is very easy to implement and there is no open-source solution to something so trivial.

Comment: I don't believe it to be as trivial as you are making it out to be.  CSV parsing in general sounds trivial until you actually try to implement it and then you find edge case after edge case...

Comment: The edge cases are more compatibility issues with different programs that implement it differently. As a rule, though I strive for compatibility with Excel. That said, it's not THAT difficult, but it's not necessarily just String.split() trivial either (quoting, escaping, and embedded newlines being the biggest issues, typically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer is "No," there is not a library that has all I wanted.  Will's solution did not include the type of pre-processing that I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.    [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) lets you choose the delimiter, in affect making it able to read all kinds of files

Comment: That appears to only cover part of what I'm looking for.  In Step 3 of the Excel Wizard a user can indicate that columns 1 and 2 are dates, columns 3-5 are text, column 6 is general, etc.  I was hoping for some similar functionality to help with some preprocessing issues like that.  I know adding stuff like that is not rocket science but I was hoping to not have to reinvent the wheel (which also exposes me to all the gotchas that everyone else has already found).

Comment: For figuring out the columns I would say use the native java methods. new Integer(col1).intValue();  (wrap it in a try catch of course)